# Trigger vs C# Command

Tags: c#, sql-server, triggers

I have a SQL Server table that contains both files and folders entries.

Meanwhile I want to create another table to create some sort of tracking about what was done to files and folders.

```
Id          OperationType    FileFolderId
----------- ---------------- -----------
1           Added            4511
2           Renamed          4511
3           Deleted          4511
4           Updated          8044
```

So what is being heavily discussed with all my other colleagues is about the best option to do this :

1. Create a trigger

or

2. Doing it on the C# side on the CRUD commands we have

The key thing here is that we don't want to cause any performance delays to the main table, that's our main critical table. We can also live with the fact that this new table might not reflect all operations for the sake of not having any kind of locks.

Comment: Well, a trigger would certainly help listen for changes in the database regardless of how it was interacted with. You haven't mentioned how you would listen for changes in database/folder in C#.

Comment: @DanielShillcock Hi Daniel. In C# I would just add an additional insert everywhere I do the operations on that main table.

Comment: I would lean towards doing this programatically rather than using a trigger. For example, you have more control using C# - what if someone performs an insert manually on the database table; the trigger would execute.

Comment: I understand perfectly, that is one of the cons on using triggers.

Comment: With regards to performance, I don't envisage causing any performance issues if you are doing this using C#. Perform your normal operations with that table, and then manage the tracking in another scope.

Comment: What do you mean with "manage the tracking in another scope" ? I'm using EF, you mean another context ?